# How do you designate private or protected attributes in Ruby/Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, attributes, access-specifier

How do you designate private or protected attributes in Ruby/Rails?

Are all DB fields automatically attributes, and don't need to be defined in the Model?

Any recommended tutorials?

Working in Rails 3.0.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `attr_protected`, `attr_accessible` or `attr_readonly`

The [attr_protected](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods/attr_protected), [attr_readonly](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attr_readonly/class) and [attr_accessible](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods/attr_accessible) macros control what is accepted for mass-assignment. Read those links if you’re not familiar with the difference between those three macros.

Documentation of ActiveRecord model:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base

Answer (score 1):

The title doesn't match the question.

Yes, DB fields are automatically attributes (depending on what you mean by attribute; they're *not* simply `@column_name` as with `attr_accessor`).

You can provide some level of accessibility by using [`attr_accessible`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods/attr_accessible) and [`attr_protected`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods/attr_protected), but that's for mass-assignment, not general access.